# How can my server code record a purchase inside my Google Analytics instance?

Tags: google-analytics

I have Analytics set up on my ecommerce web site (all custom coded). It records purchases made through the web site and monitors site traffic.

I also have scripts running on a cron job that automatically charge my customers recurring fees for the products they have ordered.

I'd like to add to those scripts an API call back to Google Analytics that tells Analytics to record that additional revenue and which product was paid for, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Measurement Protocol is the solution for this - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1